# Numerical Derivative after numerical integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

I am trying to find the numerical derivative of a function whose argument defines the bounds of a numerical integral.

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
test[u_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[x^5, {x, 0, u}]
ND[test[u], u, 2]
```

When I input this I receive the following error message: "NIntegrate::nlim: x = u is not a valid limit of integration." I figured that the inclusion of `?NumericQ` in the function definition would take care of this type of issue. Can someone explain why I am receiving this error message?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Evaluate `ClearAll@test` and try again.

Comment: With Mathematica 10.1, I receive no error message, but `ND[test[u], u, 2]` returns unevaluated.  However, if I begin the notebook with the required `Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]`, it returns `32`, as it should

Comment: @bbgodfrey OP forgot to mention that one has to load the `NumericalCalculus\`` package to have access to `ND`. I cannot reproduce the error either on 10.1. I suspect that @Karsten may be right, and it may be a spurious definition problem.

Comment: @Karsten7 was right. I just had to evaluate ClearAll@test and then it worked fine. Thank you!